# SQL Relation: One Table to Multiple Tables

Tags: python, database-design, sqlalchemy

I have three tables

```py
import enum
from sqlalchemy import Column, Enum, Float, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship


@enum.unique
class TypeEnum(str, enum.Enum):
    person = "person"
    location = "location"


class Person(Base):
    name = Column(String)
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


class Location(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    city = Column(String)
    lat = Column(Float)
    lon = Column(Float)


class ExternalIdentifier(Base):
    name = Column(String)
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = Column(String)
    type = Column(Enum(TypeEnum))
    # internal_id = relationship(...)  # Problem here
```

I would like to have a mapping between ExternalIdentifier and Person/Location:

- If `ExternalIdentifier.type` is `person`, then `ExternalIdentifier.internal_id` should refer to an object from table `Person`
- Analogously if the type is `location`

Unfortunately, I have only been able to make it work by either:

1. creating fields `ExternalIdentifier.person_id/location_id` instead of `ExternalIdentifier.internal_id/type`
2. or creating tables `person/location_to_external_identifier`

Comment: I don't know if this is possible in a straightforward manner, if at all, but **it's not a good idea** anyway. In SQL, you'd need to use a procedure to get the referenced data and not possible via a simple query. Or in Python, you'd need two second separate queries to execute a lookup on either `Location` or `Person` based on `type`. (The answer I posted had the same two alternatives as the two methods you've already posted; so I've deleted it.)

Comment: @aneroid Unfortunately not the answer I was hoping for but thanks anyway for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I understand your pov. But keep in mind that even if there was a solution, it wouldn't be a good database design. And FWIW, the 2nd solution involving creating separate tables `person/location_to_external_identifier` for the relations is slightly better than creating the `ExternalIdentifier.person_id/location_id` fields because: _..._

Comment: If they are columns in `ExternalIdentifier` and you add or remove a relationship, you'd have to _modify the structure of an existing table_. Whereas, if the relations to diff types are individually stored in their own tables, creating a new one or dropping an old one is cleaner, easier and less-risky overall to side-effects in your code. (Perhaps that should have been my answer :-) )